# MySQL Inner join last 7 days find top sales

Tags: mysql, sql

[sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecede/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecede/1)

Tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    created_at DATE NOT NULL,
    country CHAR(10),
    total_net_revenue INT NOT NULL,
    total_gross_revenue INT NOT NULL,
    total_quantity INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
    (101,'2018-03-08',"China",150,250,20),
    (102,'2018-03-08',"China",140,280,67),
    (103,'2018-03-08',"China",150,190,15),
    (111,'2018-02-09',"China",150,190,15),
    (104,'2018-03-07',"China",150,190,15);

CREATE TABLE products_inventory(
    product_id INT NOT NULL,
    product_name CHAR(10),
    brand_name CHAR(10),
    purchase_price INT NOT NULL,
    selling_price INT NOT NULL,
    units_remaining_in_inventory INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO products_inventory VALUES
    (97,"3ds","Nintendo",100,250,40),
    (98,"Switch","Nintendo",140,280,102),
    (99,"Mini","Nintendo",40,190,30),
    (131,"Fail","Nintendo",40,190,1310);

CREATE TABLE items_in_order(
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    country CHAR(10),
    brand CHAR(10),
    product_name CHAR(10),
    product_ID INT NOT NULL,
    net_revenue INT NOT NULL,
    gross_revenue INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO items_in_order VALUES
    (101,"China","Nintendo","3ds",97,150,250,20),
    (102,"China","Nintendo","Switch",98,140,280,67),
    (103,"China","Nintendo","Mini",99,150,190,15),
    (111,"China","Nintendo","Fail",131,150,190,15),
    (104,"China","Nintendo","3ds",97,150,250,20);
```

Query:

```
SELECT i1.product_name, i1.product_id, i1.brand,
SUM(i1.net_revenue) AS net_revenue_last7days,
(p2.selling_price - p2.purchase_price) AS item_margin,
remaining_stock

FROM items_in_order i1

INNER JOIN(
  SELECT o1.order_id,o1.country,SUM(o1.total_net_revenue) AS net_revenue,
  SUM(o1.total_gross_revenue) AS gross_revenue
  FROM orders o1
  WHERE (created_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND o1.country = "China"
  GROUP BY 1,2
  ) o2
  ON o2.order_id = i1.order_id AND o2.country = i1.country AND o2.net_revenue = i1.net_revenue
  AND o2.gross_revenue = i1.gross_revenue

INNER JOIN(
  SELECT product_id, product_name, brand_name AS brand, purchase_price, selling_price,
  SUM(units_remaining_in_inventory) AS remaining_stock
  FROM products_inventory p1
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
  ) p2
  ON i1.product_id = p2.product_id AND i1.product_name = p2.product_name AND i1.brand = p2.brand

WHERE i1.country = "China" AND i1.brand = "Nintendo"
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 4 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I'm trying to get a sum of the revenue on the last 7 days of per products per brand with a join on tables: orders & items_in_order.

Is there a problem with my INNER JOIN? It should show a net revenue for the last 7 days of 300 for the 3ds.

additional info what I'm trying to achieve:

- Top revenue per items for Nintendo in China last 7 days
- Show units of current inventory of each item
- Show the margin for each item

Comment: You get the desired result when you remove `AND o2.gross_revenue = i1.gross_revenue`

Comment: Thank you, I found the mistake it was actually in the table creation, gross revenue had the wrong value for 2nd 3ds in orders table: 250 instead of 190 which explains the failure in joining data

Comment: That was my other theory.

Comment: Seems like there's lots of redundant data in your tables. Why is `country` in both `orders` and `items_in_order`? Can an item be in a different country from the order itself?

Answer (score 1):

This part of the first `JOIN` is preventing order #104 from being included:

```
AND o2.gross_revenue = i1.gross_revenue
```

The gross revenue in the `orders` table for order #104 is `190`, but it's `250` in the `items_in_order` table.

If you remove that from the `JOIN` you get `net_revenue_last7days = 300`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecede/10